# Confused about Initializing Variables/Class Members

Tags: c++

What are the differences between the following?

```
int i = 4;
int j(4);
int k{4};
```

I have tried looking at the assembly of this and was hoping for any difference but i haven't found any.
However my professor recommended me to ALWAYS use `int i{value}` for every initialization ever, no matter which type, the reasoning was because in a modern standard (i think C++17) it would always work, and the alternatives would have caveats.

Also in member initializer lists:

```
SomeClass::SomeClass(int a, int b): a(a), b{b} {}
```

() and {} seem interchangeable to me.

Comment: `()` and `{}` is interchangeable for `int`, but not for types such as `std::vector`.